# How do I hide the desktop icon for my encrypted swap partition?

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, encryption, swap

I'm running stock Xubuntu 16.04, just installed. I set up my root and swap partitions to be encrypted (LUKS). Now, however, I have an unwanted icon on my desktop for the encrypted swap partition.

[image: Desktop image showing ghost icon of encrypted partition, as if ready for mounting]

How do I hide this icon without disabling the standard appearance of icons for future drives/partitions? Is it possible to disable the appearance of just one icon like this? It appears in the sidebar of Thunar windows as well, which is undesired.

The strange thing is that my encrypted root partition, which is set up exactly the same way, doesn't appear like this.

Comment: I don't have XFCE desktop running, but can't you hide it from the right-click context menu of the icon? Or is that a Unity specific thing?

Comment: Should be something like: right click desktop, chose desktop options, one of the tabs will have icon choices (may need to scroll down), uncheck 'show mounted volumes on desktop'. I think this will do it, although I've never seen swap show up before (maybe encryption affects it?)

Comment: @ByteCommander There is no hide option in the context menu.

Comment: @chaskes You can hide categories of icons, but I just one to hide this one. Ultimately it seems like a bug that it appears at all, since it's already in use by the mapper.

Comment: I agree. I can't say I've ever seen swap show up like that before.

Answer (score 1):

Check partitions using fdisk

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Edit or create file 99-hide-disks.rules

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules
```

add line

```
KERNEL=="partition_name", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

in your case it will be:

```
KERNEL=="nvme0n1p7", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

Reboot.
All done.